# URL Routing not rendering called page correctly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, url-routing

The normal Href below works properly and renders called page properly, however URL is not hidden.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rCompany" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsCompany" >
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="col4" id="trip_third">
<a href="discover_detail.aspx?Companies_PKID=<%# Eval("Companies_PKID").ToString() %>">    
    ....... 
</a>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

After adding Global.asax below ...

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
//Code that runs on application startup
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
routes.MapPageRoute(
"RouteForDiscover_Detail",
"discover_detail/{Companies_PKID}",
"~/discover_detail.aspx");
}
```

and changing Href to ...

```
<a href="<%#GetRouteUrl("RouteForDiscover_Detail", new {Companies_PKID=Eval("Companies_PKID").ToString()})%>" >
```

The URL is rewritten as expected but the called page is rendered 'totally incorrectly'.

What am I missing here ppl?

Thanks for your attention to this matter in advance.
Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

(Greatly scaled down Called Page but acts the same with 2 above different calls)
discover_detail.aspx (This is not my HTML code)
Also Note that SelectCommand(s) are hard-coded for simplicity to make sure they are not the cause.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="discover_detail.aspx.cs" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.Security" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script runat="server">
new void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Request.QueryString["Companies_PKID"] == null)
{
sdsCompany.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [DiscoverShare].[dbo].[Companies] OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [DiscoverShare].[dbo].[Image] WHERE Image.Company_PKID = Companies.Companies_PKID) i1 WHERE Companies.Companies_PKID = 464";
sdsImage.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [DiscoverShare].[dbo].[Image] WHERE Image.Company_PKID = 464";
}
else
{
sdsCompany.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [DiscoverShare].[dbo].[Companies] OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [DiscoverShare].[dbo].[Image] WHERE Image.Company_PKID = Companies.Companies_PKID) i1 WHERE Companies.Companies_PKID = 464";
sdsImage.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [DiscoverShare].[dbo].[Image] WHERE Image.Company_PKID = 464";
}
}
</script>
<html lang="en-us" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>DiscoverShare | Explore.Achieve.Connect</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../assets/images/favicon.ico" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/scrolltopcontrol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum scale=1">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsCompany" runat="server"
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DiscoverShareConnectionString2 %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DiscoverShare].[dbo].[Companies]
                        WHERE Companies_PKID = 517">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Companies_PKID" 
                 QueryStringField="Companies_PKID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsImage" runat="server"
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DiscoverShareConnectionString2 %>"
         SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DiscoverShare].[dbo].[Image] WHERE Image.Company_PKID = 517">
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Companies_PKID" 
                 QueryStringField="Companies_PKID" Type="Int32" />
         </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</body>
<form id="login" runat="server">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="brand" href="default.aspx"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" height="40" width="200" /></a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="AddActivity.aspx">Add Activity</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ReviewActivity.aspx">Review Activity</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><asp:LoginName ID="LoginName2" runat="server" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" /> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="mytrips.aspx">Bucket List</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="settings.aspx">Settings</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="findfriends.aspx">Find Friends</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="nav-header">Login/Out</li>
                                    <%--<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>--%>
                                    <li id="login_button"><asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="verdana"
                                         Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" 
                                         LoginImageUrl="~/assets/images/login.png" LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage"
                                         LogoutImageUrl="~/assets/images/logout.png" LogoutPageUrl="~/login.aspx" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="footer_wrap">
        <footer class="row">
            <div class="standard-footer">
                <p><span style="margin: 0 10px;">&copy;2012 DiscoverShare&trade;</span> | <a href="/about">Business</a> | <a href="/contact">Brand</a> | <a href="http://twitter.com/" target="_blank">About Us</a> | <a href="/terms">Privacy</a> | <a href="/privacy">Jobs</a> | <a href="/privacy">Terms</a> | <a href="/privacy">Help</a></p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/gumby.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </form>
```

Comment: 'The page is rendered totally incorrectly'...can you expand please? What exactly do you see? What is totally incorrect about it?

Comment: The Header/Footer of the HTML, Images not showing, JS not running. The whole page is FUBAR'd. Nothing rendered properly. Could I be missing something in the called page? Should it recieve the call differently than the normal Href?

Comment: shouldn't the route definition be "discover_detail/{Companies_PKID}",  (missing a left angle bracket) ?

Comment: @ Miike -- That could be the case but unlikely. In attempting to debug, I hard-coded old Href to a Companies_PKID that I know does not exist. The HTML head/footer appear correctly ... just no Template (as expected).

Comment: @AlsProtocol well that depends if your page logic is only running correctly when a querystring exists... I guess the other thing to check is that your style sheets are being referenced correctly as well.

Comment: @jbl -- Good guess, but is in the code, I guess it got missed or removed during question composition

Comment: I guess you have relative paths in your aspx page which is at the root of your app (~/discover_detail.aspx)  that get broken when the url is one level deep (discover_detail/Companies_PKID). You should rely on absolute paths

Comment: @Mike -- Thanks, I will check into it and get back shortly ...

Comment: Could I be missing something in web.config????????

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide a little more code for us to be able to completely help, but I have a strong feeling this is your prob:

In your first example, you were using a querystring to pass `Companies_PKID`, so I guess you code behind had something like:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Companies_PKID"]))
{
    string blah = (Request.QueryString["Companies_PKID"]).ToString();
}
```

Now you need to get the value differently:

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["Companies_PKID"] != null)
{
    string blah = Page.RouteData.Values["Companies_PKID"].ToString();
}
```

Note, you'll want to check for both the querystring and the route data.

The other thing you'll want to ensure is that the paths to your style sheets, etc, are correct.

Comment: After stripping out all code that references anything and leaving only <html> <body> and <form>, it is still FUBAR'd. What is going on here?

Comment: @AlsProtocol Just saying it is FUBARd doesn't describe the problem or show us what is going on. As many people have already said, you need to include relevant code.

Comment: If you look in Fiddler, what URLs is the browser seeking for images, javascript, etc?

Comment: @Amy -- I have taken out all references to images for simplicity and still face incorrent rendering of page but MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

All your relative references are wrong now since the requested URL is in a virtual subdirectory (discover_detail).  You need to change all your references to images, stylesheets, etc to using an app-relative version instead.

Not the only ones, but this should get you closer:

```
<link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/assets/images/favicon.ico" />
<link runat="server" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link runat="server" href="~/css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<% Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/js/scrolltopcontrol.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<% Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/js/modernizr.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link runat="server" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<link runat="server" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/ie.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="<% Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<% Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

** Editted to manually resolve app-relative URLs

Comment: This is in addition to changing all your references to QueryString to RouteValues as you are no longer using the QueryString for passing your values around.  QueryStringParameter will need to become RouteValueParameter or an equivalent (I don't think RouteValueParameter actually exists).

Comment: Additionally, debugging with their firebug in firefox, looking at the net tab would indicate all your externals are getting 404 not found errors, or using fiddler2 as a proxy would indicate the same.  Via Chrome, hit F12 then select the network tab, etc etc.

Comment: I need both QueryString and RouteValues for 2 different types of users hence the 'if' Statement in code-behind

Comment: You can definitely hide most of that stuff behind if statements, but you might want to consider using URL Rewriting to just send the older .aspx calls to your new format so you don't have to.

Comment: I just checked Page.Route.DataValues are getting passed properly

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken about the app-relative URLs for non-server controls being expanded in the latest web forms, it is a razor view only feature.  You'll need to add runat="server" on all your link elements, and use `<% Page.ResolveClientUrl(...) %>` in your script tags to get app-relative URLs.  Updated example header above with these changes.

Comment: Of course, for stylesheets and scripts you could implement the bundling and minification that's available built in to ASP.NET 4.5, or include the appropriate libraries from NuGet for older versions as well.  Not only would this fix the app-relative URL issues, but it would also speed up your page by requiring less requests, and making all your styles and scripts smaller.